# How to extract text from stamp using python?

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to take out the text from a stamp on a digital pdf.
Following is the image of the stamp:

[image]

Is there a particular way take out the text(Name of the organisation in particular) from this stamp . I tried to convert this image into a digital pdf using ocrmypdf and also used some cv2 commands but got no result....I am not much familiar with the cv2 library yet..Is there a way to do this using that library or any other way?

Or can I somehow use all the letters as symbols and search those symbols in the image and thus get the letters one by one and then the name of the organisation.

Comment: You can try first convert it to image and try with tesseract ocr

Comment: it is already in an image form and tesseract did not work

Comment: Which version of tesseract you are using?

Comment: have you tried this ? https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

Comment: I am using the following version:  
tesseract v5.0.0-alpha.20191030

 leptonica-1.78.0

pytesseract 0.3.4